# Python, make a list for a for loop when parsing a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on parsing a CSV from an export of my company's database. This is a slimmed down version has around 15 columns, the actual CSV has over 400 columns of data (all necessary). The below works perfectly:

```
inv = csv.reader(open('inventory_report.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel', delimiter="\t")

for PART_CODE,MODEL_NUMBER,PRODUCT_NAME,COLOR,TOTAL_ONHAND,TOTAL_ON_ORDER,TOTAL_SALES,\
SALES_YEAR_TO_DATE,SALES_LASTYEAR_TO_DATE,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_QTYsSOLD,TOTAL_PURCHASES,\
PURCHASES_YEAR_TO_DATE,PURCHASES_LASTYEAR_TO_DATE,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_QTYpurchased,\
DATE_LAST_SOLD,DATE_FIRST_SOLD in inv:
    print ('%-20s %-90s OnHand: %-10s OnOrder: %-10s') % (MODEL_NUMBER,PRODUCT_NAME,\
    TOTAL_ONHAND,TOTAL_ON_ORDER)
```

As you can already tell, it will be very painful to read when the 'for' loop has 400+ names attached to it for each of item of the row in the CSV. However annoying, it is however very handy for being able to access the output I'm after by this method. I can easily get specific items and perform calculations within the common names we're already familiar with in our point of sale database.

I've been attempting to make this more readable. Trying to figure out a way where I could define a list of all these names in the for loop but still be able to call for them by name when it's time to do calculations and print the output.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your CSV file have a header row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use csv.DictReader. Elements are read as dict. Assuming u have first line as column name.

```
inv = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv')):
for i in inv:
  print ('%-20s %-90s OnHand: %-10s OnOrder: %-10s') % (i['MODEL_NUMBER'],i['PRODUCT_NAME'],i['TOTAL_ONHAND'],i['TOTAL_ON_ORDER'])
```

And if you want the i[MODEL_NUMBER] to come from list. Define a list with all column name. Assuming, `l = ['MODEL_NUMBER','PRODUCT_NAME','TOTAL_ONHAND','TOTAL_ON_ORDER']`. Then my print statement in above code will be,

```
print ('%-20s %-90s OnHand: %-10s OnOrder: %-10s') % (i[l[0]],i[l[1]],i[l[2]],i[l[3]])
```

Code not checked.. :)

Comment: DictReader is a good suggestion, my file doesn't have headers but I'm sure I could add them in the script and then read them in afterwards. Using a list makes building the output pretty human-unfriendly with 400+ items to work with. Thanks none-the-less however!

Comment: Updated my export file to include headers, worked like a champ. Thank you so much, I'm very green to programming and have only been programming in Python for a month. Learned a great deal from stackoverflow and learnpythonthehardway.org

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more readable and easier to reuse, you should read the name of the columns dynamically. CSV files use to have a header with this information on top of the file, so you can read the first line and store it in a tuple or a list.

Comment: My file doesn't have headers, but I guess I could add to the program to add headers to the file and then read it back in. That could work!